# Chebyshev's inequality for sample means

Tags: statistics, random-variables

I understand how to use chebyshev's inequality for basic questions, but how do I apply chebyshev's inequality to probabilities of simple random sample groups? For example the question,
a random variable X has mean $μ = 8$ and $\sigma = 3$. A simple random sample of size $15$ is picked from this population described by $X$.

What is the largest possible value of
$P (|\overline X − 8| ≥ 2)$?

Comment: $P(|\bar{X}-8|)$ doesn't make sense, do you mean to write $P(|\bar{X} - 8| \ge 2)$ instead? If so, what does chebyshev tell you about $|\bar{X} - \mu|$ ?

Comment: Hint: $\overline X$ has a mean of $8$ and a variance $0.6$. So the largest possible value is ...

Comment: @WeakLearner yes that's what I meant, sorry. So in this case would I just solve the problem as if its a regular chebyshev problem? |¯−| must be less than or equal to 1/k^2?

Comment: @callculus42 where do you get variance = .6? wouldn't k = 2/σ = .67? and from that I get that the largest possible value is 1/k^2, 2.25?

Comment: Not really. The inequality is $P (|\overline X − 8| ≥ 2)\leq \frac1{k^2}$, where $2=k\cdot \sigma$ and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of $\overline X$

Comment: It is $Var(\overline X)=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$, where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the population.

Comment: @DanielLader Everything clear so far?

Comment: @callculus42 That helps a lot, thank you

Comment: @DanielLader That pleases me. You're welcome.